# Python retrieve row index of a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Could I ask how to retrieve an index of a row in a DataFrame?
Specifically, I am able to retrieve the index of rows from a df.loc.

```
idx = data.loc[data.name == "Smith"].index
```

I can even retrieve row index from df.loc by using data.index like this:

```
idx = data.loc[data.index == 5].index
```

However, I cannot retrieve the index directly from the row itself (i.e., from row.index, instead of df.loc[].index). I tried using these codes:

```
idx = data.iloc[5].index
```

The result of this code is the column names.

To provide context, the reason I need to retrieve the index of a specific row (instead of rows from df.loc) is to use df.apply for each row.
I plan to use df.apply to apply a code to each row and copy the data from the row immediately above them.

```
def retrieve_gender (row):
    # This is a panel data, whose only data in 2000 is already keyed in. Time-invariant data in later years are the same as those in 2000.
    if row["Year"] == 2000:
        pass
    elif row["Year"] == 2001: # To avoid complexity, let's use only year 2001 as example.
        idx = row.index # This is wrong code.
        row["Gender"] = row.iloc[idx-1]["Gender"]
    return row["Gender"]


data["Gender"] = data.apply(retrieve_gender, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

With Pandas you can loop through your dataframe like this :

```
for index in range(len(df)): 
    if df.loc[index,'year'] == "2001":
        df.loc[index,'Gender'] = df.loc[index-1 ,'Gender']
```

Comment: I actually wrote a retrieve_data(df) that uses iterrows(), instead of retrieve_data(row), and it worked. But I 'm just curious just in case. So there is no way this can be done by df.apply to each individual row, isn't there?

Answer (score 0):

#### `apply` gives series indexed by column labels

The problem with `idx = data.iloc[5].index` is `data.iloc[5]` converts a row to a `pd.Series` object *indexed by column labels*.

In fact, what you are asking for is **impossible via [`pd.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)** because the series that feeds your `retrieve_gender` function does not include any index identifier.

#### Use vectorised logic instead

With Pandas row-wise logic is inefficient and not recommended; it involves a Python-level loop. Use columnwise logic instead. Taking a step back, it seems you wish to implement 2 rules:

1. If `Year` is not 2001, leave `Gender` unchanged.
2. If `Year` is 2001, use `Gender` from previous row.

#### `np.where` + `shift`

For the above logic, you can use [`np.where`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`pd.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
data['Gender'] = np.where(data['Year'] == 2001, data['Gender'].shift(), data['Gender'])
```

#### `mask` + `shift`

Alternatively, you can use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) + `shift`:

```
data['Gender'] = data['Gender'].mask(data['Year'] == 2001, data['Gender'].shift())
```